# WSO2 web services to get the days left for password expiry

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 in a project and i need to get the number of days left for password expiry for a given user, via some web service interface, so that a warning could be displayed upon login. 
Didn't find any operation in the web service endpoints i know about. Could any one help?  Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK its not available under IS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, there is no out of box service for doing this.We had somewhat similar requirement which we accomplished by creating a custom operation in User Management Web Service. Below is the way by which you may achieve this:

In case you are using LDAP as user store then you may configure the password expiration policy there. And then you may create a custom operation which will check the applicable password policy for the given user and fetch password expiration interval and then calculate the number of days left by comparing the last password changed time from LDAP. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Yusuf. i think this may be the route i would need to adopt. i tried to use ldapbrowser to check on the values and the passwordtimestamp is empty. how do i tell WSO2 to update those fields?